# Issues with Cefsharp and foreach loop

Tags: c#, asynchronous, foreach, async-await, cefsharp

I'm new to working with async and I'm trying to build a Cefsharp application that collects data from an external API, stores it in local variables and then exports these through JavaScript to HTML. It's not a beautiful implementation and I'm sure my code is pretty awful but here goes:

My application performs a tick every 5 seconds, where it executes a HTTP Post request and stores the result in a QuickType (app.quicktype.io) list. This is the tick:

```cs
private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await chromeBrowser.WaitForInitialLoadAsync();

    if (httpPost.ConnectionSuccesful())
    {
        var devtoolsContext = await chromeBrowser.CreateDevToolsContextAsync();
        var postResult = await httpPost.SendPost("robot_info");

        try {
            var result = Welcome.FromJson(postResult);

            foreach (var robot in result.Result.Robots.Select((value, i) => (value, i)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(robot.value.Id);

                if (robot.value.ChargingStateCode == 9 || robot.value.ChargingStateCode == 12)
                    await devtoolsContext.EvaluateFunctionAsync("function setBatteryCharge() { var batteryLevel = jQuery('#robot" + robot.i + "Charge'); batteryLevel.css('width', "+ robot.value.StateOfCharge + " + '%'); batteryLevel.text('Charging'); batteryLevel.addClass('high'); batteryLevel.removeClass('medium'); batteryLevel.removeClass('low'); }");
                else if (robot.value.StateOfCharge > 75)
                    await devtoolsContext.EvaluateFunctionAsync("function setBatteryHigh() { var batteryLevel = jQuery('#robot" + robot.i + "Charge'); batteryLevel.css('width', " + robot.value.StateOfCharge + " + '%'); batteryLevel.text(" + robot.value.StateOfCharge + " + '%'); batteryLevel.addClass('high'); batteryLevel.removeClass('medium'); batteryLevel.removeClass('low'); }");
                else if (robot.value.StateOfCharge >= 50)
                    await devtoolsContext.EvaluateFunctionAsync("function setBatteryMedium() { var batteryLevel = jQuery('#robot" + robot.i + "Charge'); batteryLevel.css('width', " + robot.value.StateOfCharge + " + '%'); batteryLevel.text(" + robot.value.StateOfCharge + " + '%'); batteryLevel.addClass('medium'); batteryLevel.removeClass('high'); batteryLevel.removeClass('low'); }");
                else
                    await devtoolsContext.EvaluateFunctionAsync("function setBatteryLow() { var batteryLevel = jQuery('#robot" + robot.i + "Charge'); batteryLevel.css('width', " + robot.value.StateOfCharge + " + '%'); batteryLevel.text(" + robot.value.StateOfCharge + " + '%'); batteryLevel.addClass('low'); batteryLevel.removeClass('high'); batteryLevel.removeClass('medium'); }");
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException Nex) {
            Console.Write("[Error] - " + Nex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[Error] - " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("[Error] - Check connection or access to API server.");
}
```

I'm currently trying to update the battery level and it successfully does this for the first tick (the JavaScript works as intended and both the css, classes and text is changed). Then it stops working. I've checked that the correct results are coming in from the HTTP Post and that the data is stored properly in the local variables. The problem seems to occur in the `foreach`. I've tried to read up about async a bit but I can't seem to find the culprit. After the first execution of the code, something seems to be blocking the iteration  of the for each. I'm using `Cefsharp.Winforms` and `Cefsharp.Puppeteer`.

Any idea on why this is happening? Also thankful for any pointers or tips on how to improve the code.

EDIT: This is the Console Output

```
[Query] Sending post request to xxx with method 'robot_info'
[Success] - API Post Request was succesful.
PR1@11
PR1@15
[Query] Sending post request to xxx with method 'robot_info'
[Success] - API Post Request was succesful.
PR1@11
[Query] Sending post request to xxx with method 'robot_info'
[Success] - API Post Request was succesful.
PR1@11
```

The first iteration goes through fine.

EDIT2: This is the timer

```cs
public void InitTimer()
{
    timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Interval = 5000;
    timer1.Start();
}
```

EDIT3: Method SendPost

```cs
public async Task<string> SendPost(string method)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    
    string data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
    {
        jsonrpc = "2.0",
        method = method,
        id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    });

    StringContent content = new StringContent(data, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[Query] Sending post request to " + url.ToString() + " with method '" + method + "'");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (IsValidJson(result))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[Success] - API Post Request was succesful.");
            return result;
        }
        else
            return null;

    } catch (HttpRequestException hre)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[Error]: " + hre);
        return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT4: Structure of Welcome

```
    public partial class Welcome
    {
        [JsonProperty("jsonrpc")]
        public string Jsonrpc { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public Result Result { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Result
    {
        [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
        public long Timestamp { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("robots")]
        public List<Robot> Robots { get; set; }
    }
```

Robots is a list with a bunch of longs and ints.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243482/discussion-on-question-by-lemonslayer-cant-get-async-method-to-perform-foreach).

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/Puppeteer#devtoolscontext  you can only have a single DevToolsContext instance at a time. Best to reuse a single instance where possible.

Comment: There's an example at https://github.com/cefsharp/Puppeteer/blob/main/lib/CefSharp.Puppeteer.WinForms.Example/BrowserForm.cs#L211

Comment: Thank you @amaitland, I'll make sure to try it out!